A child overflows parent despite having max-height set to 100% of its parent and parent has explicitly defined height
Not sure how this is possible and what's causing said bug.
I researched answers here and they all seem to point that cause of error is one of two things.
Parent not having height defined so child max height looks at parent explicit height and computers to none but here div named main-container clearly has height defined based on body element which also has explicitly defined height of 100vh as starting point.
Second answer I found is that there must be additional element on top of given element that cause overflow within parent. But that's not the case here either since it's obviously the child element itself that bigger than parent.
Now I know why overflow happens later down the line once cards come into play but that's not important here.What I cannot understand and what I'm interested in is how does a child div that has clearly set max height to 100% still manage to be bigger than its parent?
Here is the css code and screenshots showing relevant html structure and what happening.
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,body{
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
}

body>div{
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

div{
    border: none;
}

h2{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#main-container{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
}

#sidebar{
    background-color:#3b82f6;
}

#sidebar-header{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
    gap:50px;
    align-items: center;
    border:none;
    margin-bottom: 125px;
    padding-left:50px;
}

#sidebar-header-image{
    height: 170px;
}

#sidebar-heading{
    font-size:80px;
}

#first-sidebar-container{
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

li{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 150px;
    gap:80px;
}

.icon{
    height: 70px;
    filter:invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(338deg) brightness(102%) contrast(105%);
    justify-self: right; 
}

.icon-text{
    font-size: 60px;
    border: none;
}


.sidebar-container{
    display:grid;
    list-style:none;
}

.sidebar-container.first{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#main-body{
    max-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: white;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    color:black;
}

#header{
    box-shadow: 1px 9px #E5E7EB;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#header-top-section{
    margin-top:40px;
    display:flex;
    gap: 60px;
    align-items:center;
}

.header-icon:nth-child(1){
    margin-left:100px;
}

.header-icon:nth-child(3){
    margin-left:300px;
}

.header-icon{
    height:75px;
}

#search{
    flex-grow:1;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#top-profile-picture{
    height:150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#top-username{
    margin-right: 250px;;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

#main-header-section{
    height: 240px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.8fr 1fr;
    margin: 80px 120px 50px;
    padding-right:30px;
}

#profile-section{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
    column-gap: 60px;
    row-gap:30px;
}

#main-profile-picture{
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}

#side-text{
    font-size:40px;
    align-self: end;
}

#profile-name{
    font-size:70px;
    align-self: start;
}

#options-section{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.option{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#3b82f6;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width:300px;
    height:115px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size:45px;
    color:white;
}

#main-content{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1.2fr;
    gap:60px;
    padding: 95px 100px 130px;
}

#main-content>div{
    border: 3px black solid;
}

#cards-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

#cards-header{
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

#cards{
    max-height: 100%;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 30% 30% 30%;
    gap:75px;
    padding-top: 20px;;
}



Set overflow, otherwise parent will be stretched beyond max-height/height

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Justinas thanks for advice its can definitely work but doesn't setting something like overflow hidden only cut off content without resizing it? Sorry I forgot to mention that I cant have content be cut I forgot to mention that so that not what I want exactly in given case. I just want given element to be resized to fit the parent as I expected would happen when I set size 100%. So if my goal isn't to cut content but just have it all fit size of whole screen/viewport exactly no more or less and since my solution doesn't work how would you go about doing it?

@Justinas btw the cards seem to be main issue at least to me but I cant set their size explicitly to certain number of pixels since that doesn't seem like best solution more often than not the container holding them will end up either too small or too big by a little bit so it wont fit screen as needed plus what if number of them changes later down the road. Much better solution would be to have them resize automatically but also have container be exactly that fits viewport so I was hoping 100% height of parent would do the trick since it would be ideal but that doesn't work.What do you think?

@20centuryboy For text - add overflow: auto, so there will be scrollbars. For others - use Flex
